# How to approach in showing values from row in columns in gridview devexpress

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have devexpress gridview and the data for this girdview comes from two tables. Below is the structure of these two tables. In table1 you can say ProductID column is unique, in table2 ProductID can be repeated. I want to display in gridview each row for each productID.

I dont want to use PIVOT on table2 since every time new value is inserted for a product I have to change LINQ enitity or database object.

Table1

### ProductID ColumnA ColumnB

1------------------------x-------------------------Y

Table2

### ProductID Column  Values

1----------------ColumnC--------Z

1----------------ColumnD--------A

So In Grid I want

### ProductID ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD

Do I need to use datatable in asp.net(if so how) and pass this datatable as datasource to grid? or can I use lists (if so how?)

I aslo want to export whatever datapresent in grid to excel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the Master-Detail view:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/MasterDetail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/exporting/Exporting.aspx) for exporting `GridViews`.

To accomplish your task, I think you can just do something like :

```
foreach (Table1Class table1Class in Table1ClassList) // Table1ClassList contains all the records from Table1
{
    foreach (Table2Class table2Class in Table2ClassList.Where(e => e.ProductID.Equals(table1Class.ProductId)))
    {
        // Retrieving Column : your FieldNames should be correctly set
        GridColumn columnFromGrid = FinalGrid.Columns.Where(col => col.FieldName.Equals(table2Class.Column)).First();

        // TODO : Populating Column
    }
}
```

I think this should do the trick !